# Labeling arcs in MathJAX

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there any capability to label arcs as we may label line segments, i.e., $\overline{AB}$?  I can't seem to find anything that allows us to use the [tricks I see online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96680/a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook) within MathJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}$?

`$\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}$`

It's not great if you want a three-letters arc, though: $\arc{ABC}$. Still does the trick, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Asaf.  That is fine here.  Unfortunately, I failed to mention that it is for the blog, where MathJAX is a bit inferior.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
$\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{ABC\,}$
```

which produces $\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{ABC\,}$?

Comment: Oh, that's nice.